# is it an access issue or a permissions issue?

Tags: fedora, permissions, chown

I've been having problems with accessing files these days. In the course of solving this problem, I tried changing the ownership from `root` to `ar.lnx` and this is what I got

```
[ar.lnx@host DATA] $ cd /mnt/DATA
[ar.lnx@host DATA] $ ls -l
total 832
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  32768 Jan 10 09:52 1
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root  32768 Jan 22 14:36 Audio
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  32768 Jan 10 09:48 Compressed
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  32768 Jan 22 19:22 Dev Workshop
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  32768 Jan 10 11:40 ISO
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  32768 Jan 17 12:10 Knowledge
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  32768 Jan 11 01:30 Photos
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  32768 Dec  3 20:24 print
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  40354 Jan 22 22:57 rpm-pack.catalog
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 335462 Jan 11 23:11 Solarized (dark).kateschema
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  32768 Jan 11 00:53 Tattoo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    320 Dec 26 15:53 network-list
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      2 Dec 26 15:53 network-list~
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  32768 Jan 11 03:19 Windows(.exe)
[ar.lnx@host DATA] $ su
Password: 
[root@host DATA] # sudo chown ar.lnx:ar.lnx /mnt/DATA -R
chown: changing ownership of ‘/mnt/DATA/1/PP1-CS6-start.pdf’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/mnt/DATA/1/PP1-CS6-start1.odg’: Operation not permitted
.
.
.
chown: changing ownership of ‘/mnt/DATA/Audio’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/mnt/DATA’: Operation not permitted
[root@host DATA] #
```

why do I get "Operation not permitted?" and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What does `df /mnt/DATA` show? I suspect you've mounted a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM.

Comment: Or a storage device with read only permission , i remember sandisk have such issues

Comment: @JeffSchaller 
`Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       68643776 55656960  12986816  82% /mnt/DATA` where is the issue ?

Comment: Does `sudo touch /mnt/DATA/1/test` create a file?

Comment: is /mnt/DATA a FAT (i.e. windows or ms-dos) filesystem?  FAT doesn't support file permissions or ownership.

Comment: Yes it is (FAT32), so i have to change the format, isn't it?

Comment: @cas Put that as an answer?

Comment: (1) Once you've done `su` and you're getting a `# ` prompt, you don't need to use `sudo`.  (2) If `/mnt` is FAT, then that's the answer.  But another possible explanation would be that the file system is remote, NFS-mounted from a file server, and the file server isn't recognizing the authority of `root` processes on the local (client) machine to perform privileged operations on files on the server.  (It would be possible that this could be fixed by changing `mount` options, or it might require a configuration setting change on the file server.)

Comment: i 'm using fedora workstation not fedora server? is that applied on me too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/mnt/DATA` is likely a FAT (i.e. windows or ms-dos) filesystem, and FAT doesn't support unix file permissions or ownership.  If not FAT, then some other fs type that doesn't support unix ownership or perms, but FAT is most likely.

You don't need to change the format unless ownership or perms are important to you - if you just want to transfer the files around using `/mnt/DATA` (presumably a USB stick) then you can just ignore the `Operation not permitted` error messages.

If owner/perms are important, then reformat as, e.g., ext4.

If you just want `/mnt/DATA` to be owned by a particular owner or group when mounted, then you can use the `uid=` and/or `gid=` mount options.  You can also set the `umask`, `dmask`, and `fmask` values, which affect the default (faked/emulated) perms of created files and/or dirs.

See `man mount` and search for `Mount options for fat` for details.

Comment: that was really helpful, that you so much @cas